# Slider left button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, slider

I worked a lot trying to fix this thing, and I finally got to just one problem left. When going to the left, trying to go behind the first slide should take you to the last one. All it does here, is continuing to go back, deeper into the nothingness. You can see the current version here: http://ice-trance.tk.

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {

var width = 720;
var animationSpeed = 838;
var pause = 5900;
var currentSlide = 1;

var $slider = $('#slide');
var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide');
var $left = $slider.find('#prevSlide');
var $right = $slider.find('#nextSlide');

var interval;

function startSlider(){
interval = setInterval(function() {
    $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
        currentSlide++;
        if (currentSlide === $slides.length) {
        currentSlide = 1;
        $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
        }
    });
}, pause);
};

$slider.on('mouseenter', function() {
$('.slide-ctrl').delay(42).fadeIn(130);})
.on('mouseleave', function() {
$('.slide-ctrl').delay(240).fadeOut(514);});


$left.click(function() {
    $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '+='+width}, animationSpeed, function () {
      // the problem
        currentSlide++;
        if (currentSlide == -1) {
        currentSlide = $slides.length;
        $slideContainer.css('margin-left', $slides.lenght);
        }
    });
});

$right.click(function() {
    $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
        currentSlide++;
        if (currentSlide === $slides.length) {
        currentSlide = 1;
        $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
        }
    });
});

function stopSlider() {
clearInterval(interval);
};

$slider.on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);
('.slide_content').on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);

startSlider();

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slide">
<div class="slide-ctrl" id="prevSlide"><</div>
<div class="slide-ctrl" id="nextSlide">></div>
<ul class="slides">
<li class="slide"><div class="slideImg slide1">
    <div class="slide_content">
    <div id="slide_contentBG"></div>
    <h3>slide 1</h3>
    </div></div></li>
<li class="slide"><div class="slideImg slide2">
    <div class="slide_content">
    <div id="slide_contentBG"></div>
    <h3>slide 2</h3>
    </div></div></li>
<li class="slide"><div class="slideImg slide3">
    <div class="slide_content">
    <div id="slide_contentBG"></div>
    <h3>slide 3</h3>
    </div></div></li>
<li class="slide"><div class="slideImg slide4">
    <div class="slide_content">
    <div id="slide_contentBG"></div>
    <h3>slide 4</h3>
    </div></div></li>
<li class="slide"><div class="slideImg slide5">
    <div class="slide_content">
    <div id="slide_contentBG"></div>
    <h3>slide 5</h3>
    </div></div></li>
<li class="slide"><div class="slideImg slide1">
    <div class="slide_content">
    <div id="slide_contentBG"></div>
    <h3>slide 1.2</h3>
    </div></div></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a syntax error in you css statement

```
$slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '+='+width}, animationSpeed, function () {
  // the problem
    currentSlide++;
    if (currentSlide == -1) {
    currentSlide = $slides.length;
    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', $slides.lenght); //This should be $slides.length not lenght
    }
});
```

Also you slideNumbering seems a bit weird. I didn't go in to detail but increasing the currentSlide index when clicking the left button seems counter intuitive to me.

I would expect

```
currentSlide--
```

Otherwise your if statement will never be true

And i would think you if statement would check for 0 as your first index is 1;

```
    if (currentSlide == 0)
```

And my last remark is that you will not get a smooth transistion here. you will first see an empty slide as your only checking for the slide index when you finished the animation. therefore I would move this logic before you start the animation.

Comment: I wonder for how long that syntax error was there... Ok, fixed that, changed the currentSlide++ back to currentSlide-- and fixed the trigger slide, now there's one thing I forgot about: it needs to change to $slides.length -1 slide. How can I do that? I'm not sure how js maths work.

Comment: you mean you want to adjust the the margin using the width?

Comment: yes, putting the margin-left to the penultimate slide. also setting currentSlide to $slides.length-1 (no idea how to do that in jquery)

Comment: just do currentSlide = $slides.length-1 and for your margin something like: $slideContainer.css('margin-left', -$slides.length*width)

Comment: There were some tweaks I had to do to that but, it's fully working. Aso added the smooth change on the left. Thanks!